# PDF generates with a very large Size when using with open html to pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox, openhtmltopdf

Hello I am trying to convert my Html to Pdf and I am using OpenHtmltoPdf for doing that. I also loading Arial Unicode MS font for that I am loading it from local directory. After including it my pdf file size is increased to nearly 100mb. Is there any way to reduce the file size

I tried with making my PdfRendererBuilder as static but still its giving the same error

Fist I have initialized my PdfRendererBuilder

```
private static PdfRendererBuilder pdfBuilder=new PdfRendererBuilder();
pdfBuilder.useFastMode();
pdfBuilder.useFont(new File("D://New//ARIAL.ttf"), "Arial Unicode MS");
```

For PDF Creation I have used

```
public void pdfCreate(){
 pdfBuilder.withHtmlContent(str.toString(), "");

PdfBoxRenderer box = pdfBuilder.buildPdfRenderer();
box.createPDFWithoutClosing();
PDFMergerUtility merge = new PDFMergerUtility()
PDDocument htmlDocument2=box.getPdfDocument();
merge.appendDocument(doc, htmlDocument2);
}
```

here doc is my original document and htmlDocument2 is the document I have generated newly. str is my html stringBuilder object.
I have to call this pdfCreate() method several times

I want to reduce the file size of the pdf

Comment: One would have to see the PDF. My guess is that the Arial Unicode font wasn't subsetted.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have tried with subsetting the font but still it was not working, Then I found another solution but its not the proper way. I saved the newly created pdf that is generated by openHtmlToPdf and after I load that pdf and merged with my original pdf. Yes I Know its not a good way but it is the only option i found

Comment: Are you saying that the file got smaller because it was merged? This suggests that the file would also get smaller just by opening and saving it again. Again, I can't comment on the size of the PDF without seeing it.